# What is Connection-specific DNS Suffix

Tags: windows, networking, dns, cmd.exe, ipconfig

I am reading the output of Windows 10 cmd `ipconfig /all`.

There is one field which I cannot understand and cannot find it on Google which is.  I am living in a dorm and I am connected to its network.

> Connection-specific DNS Suffix

What does it mean?

Answer (score 17):

In Windows, this suffix is used to:

1. be automatically added to any [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) queries that do not specify a domain name. Ex: when you try to access a website by only specifying its hostname, such as `www`. It will automatically add the suffix domain specified by the [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) (or GPO) administrator of your network to this query, turning it into the [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) `www.domainsuffixspecified.com`.
2. dynamically register the hostname of your workstation within the local network's DNS servers, turning your device into a 'member' of this network. Example: your computer is named `mypc-01`, but when it receives a DNS suffix from the DHCP (or, again, via GPO), it will be internally recognized as `mypc-01.thedomainsuffixspecified.com`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A typical example is when you setup a VPN connection and the DNS name of your computer must be registered into the DNS zone of the VPN network